# What is tempuri.org?

Tags: web-services, namespaces

Why does tempuri.org exist?  Why does each XML Webservice require its own namespace, unique from any other on the web?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Webservices require unique namespaces so they don't confuse each others schemas and whatever with each other. A URL (domain, subdomain, subsubdomain, etc) is a clever identifier as it's "guaranteed" to be unique, and in most circumstances you've already got one.

Comment: Every once in a while, you can have a situation where you're storing data from 2 (or more) sources in a single XML document (e.g. gathering info from multiple chemical manufacturers about a well-known substance) and being able to use namespaces for each manufacturer allows you to have the same Xml element tag e.g. `<comp1:SubstanceName>Hand Soap</comp1:SubstanceName>` and `<comp2:SubstanceName>Palmolive</comp2:SubstanceName>` and `<comp3:SubstanceName>Soft Soap</comp3:SubstanceName>` without collision, and with clarity where the data came from

Comment: What is tempuri.org?

Answer (score 65):

Unfortunately the `tempuri.org` URL now just redirects to Bing.

You can see what it used to render via `archive.org`:

> https://web.archive.org/web/20090304024056/http://tempuri.org/

To quote:

> Each XML Web Service needs a unique namespace in order for client
>   applications to distinguish it from other services on the Web.  By
>   default, ASP.Net Web Services use http://tempuri.org/ for this
>   purpose.  While this suitable for XML Web Services under development,
>   published services should use a unique, permanent namespace.
>
> Your XML Web Service should be identified by a namespace that you
>   control.  For example, you can use your company's Internet domain name
>   as part of the namespace.  Although many namespaces look like URLs,
>   they need not point to actual resources on the Web.
>
> For XML Web Services creating[sic] using ASP.NET, the default namespace can
>   be changed using the WebService attribute's Namespace property.  The
>   WebService attribute is applied to the class that contains the XML Web
>   Service methods.  Below is a code example that sets the namespace to
>   "http://microsoft.com/webservices/":
>
> C#
>
> ```
> [WebService(Namespace="http://microsoft.com/webservices/")]
> public class MyWebService {
>    // implementation
> }
> ```
>
> Visual Basic.NET
>
> ```
> <WebService(Namespace:="http://microsoft.com/webservices/")> Public Class MyWebService
>     ' implementation
> End Class
> ```
>
> Visual J#.NET
>
> ```
> /**@attribute WebService(Namespace="http://microsoft.com/webservices/")*/
> public class MyWebService {
>     // implementation
> }
> ```

It's also worth reading section 'A 1.3 Generating URIs' at:

http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl#_Toc492291092

Answer (score 14):

Probably to guarantee that public webservices will be unique.

It always makes me think of delicious deep fried treats...

Answer (score 13):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tempuri

> tempuri.org is the default namespace URI used by Microsoft development products, like Visual Studio.

Comment: Given the size of the article, you might as well have quoted the entire thing.

Comment: tempuri.org isn't particular to Microsoft, it's actually described in the W3C notes on WDSL: http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl#_Toc492291092 - "The base URI "http://tempuri.org/" can be used to construct a URI without any unique association to an entity"

Comment: For what it's worth it no longer seems to be the case that tempuri.org has any endorsement by w3.org (at least on that linked page)

Answer (score 7):

Note that namespaces that are in the format of a valid Web URL don't necessarily need to be dereferenced i.e. you don't need to serve actual content at that URL. All that matters is that the namespace is globally unique.