# ASMX: What should tempuri.org be replaced with?

Tags: visual-studio, web-services, namespaces, asmx

Every new web service you create using visual studio comes with a predefined namespace like this:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
```

My web service will run at different clients, and on different domains, so because of this I don't know the domain upfront during development, also I don't want to have to edit this file, each time I deploy to a new client.

What exactly should the value of Namespace be? It seems like a web address, but that doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is tempuri.org?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180985/what-is-tempuri-org)

Comment: Use http://ws-i.org/profiles/basic/1.1 or http://microsoft.com/webservices/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's kind of ironic but the best answer is under : http://tempuri.org/

quote

> Each XML Web Service needs a unique namespace in order for client applications to distinguish it from other services on the Web.  By default, ASP.Net Web Services use http://tempuri.org/ for this purpose.  While this suitable for XML Web Services under development, published services should use a unique, permanent namespace.
>
> Your XML Web Service should be
>   identified by a namespace that you
>   control.  For example, you can use
>   your company's Internet domain name as
>   part of the namespace.  Although many
>   namespaces look like URLs, they need
>   not point to actual resources on the
>   Web.
>
> For XML Web Services creating using
>   ASP.NET, the default namespace can be
>   changed using the WebService
>   attribute's Namespace property.  The
>   WebService attribute is applied to the
>   class that contains the XML Web
>   Service methods.  Below is a code
>   example that sets the namespace to
>   "http://microsoft.com/webservices/":

```
C#
[WebService(Namespace="http://microsoft.com/webservices/")]
public class MyWebService {
    // implementation
}
```

Comment: +1 and accepted answer - Lol - excuse the humor, but what if your company is too poor to afford a domain name ? :) JK

Comment: Is there a way to completely omit it? When trying to consume it with AS3 using XML class - you have to append the namespace to everything, as described here: http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=184708, and it's pretty annoying...

Comment: Ok, if you do [WebService(Namespace = null)] in the asmx.cs file, it is omitted...
(For anyone wanting to know...)

Comment: I'm sorry, but after a day (in where it worked) - it throws out 
a "can't be NULL" exception.

Answer (score 3):

Put in your domain, as developer ;)

it is basically used as resource identifier to schemata. But it seems to ahve no real use except being "part of the standard".

Answer (score 3):

`http://tempuri.org` is an example of an "XML Namespace". In this case, it happens to be the location of a page on the Web, but in general, an XML Namespace is just a text string in the form of a URI.

XML namespaces are for the purpose of making the names of XML nodes unique. The canonical example is to make sure that your `Book` element and the `Book` element of another service are of two different types and do not conflict with each other. That's the reason to use your company's domain name as part of the namespace, if possible. Your company's domain name will be unique. Presumably you are in control of all namespaces that use your company's domain name, so your company can make sure that there are no conflicts *within* the company - the uniqueness of domain names makes sure there is no conflict among domain names.